# Calling function in the bash from the same function

Tags: bash

I had wrote a function in script, and I want to call the function if the condition is not matched inside the case statement which is inside the function. Instead of calling the function again, my script is printing or echoing my function name.

```
#!/bin/bash

function askUser() {

printf " AUS for Australia \n BAN for Bangladesh \n NEP for Nepal \n IND for India \n ENG for England\n "

read -p " Guess one of the best cricket team according to the country code" read


echo $read

        TEAM="ENG"
        case $read in
        "AUS" | "BAN" | "NEP" | "IND") echo "SORRY!! You Guess the wrong team :(\n" askUser
        ;;
        "ENG") echo "England is the best cricket team and recently had won the ICC trophy. "
        ;;
        *) echo "Please select from the above Teams::):)"
        esac
}
askUser
```

Comment: You need to add `;` after this `...:(\n"`, befor function name.

Comment: thanks for your reply, that really helped for me

Comment: c.f. [List Commands](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists).

Answer (score 0):

put '&& askUser', the way you have it now does not actually call the function
the way you have it now it will pass askUser as a parameter to echo, that's why